# Number of ways to arrange a set of numbers

Tags: combinatorics

I have two numbers say $a$ and $b$. There are $n$ slots. Given numbers $[a, b]$ i.e. all numbers between $a$ and $b$ (inclusive). In how mane ways can I arrange or place these ($b - a + 1$) numbers in these $n$ slots such that there is at least 1 $a$ *and* at least 1 $b$ in these $n$ slots.

Example: If $a = 1$, and $b = 5$, and there are $n = 4$ slots. In how many ways can I arrange or place numbers $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ in these 4 slots, such that there is atleast one 1 and atleast one 5 in the set of 4 slots?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You need to

- choose $n-2$ other numbers from $b-a-1$ possibilities to add to $a$ and $b$ and
- arrange all these numbers in the $n$ slots

Comment: I came to know the answer to be
(q + 1)^n + (q + 1)^n - (2 * q^n) by union-intersection principle.

But I dont understand how.

Comment: @user2861468: What is $q$?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that q = (b - a) i.e. difference b/w a and b. So (q + 1) is the number of objects to be considered ie (b - a + 1)